# Sequence re .HTACCESS file

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I'm trying to generate a simple .htacces file for a website. At the moment there are only 3 commands and this is the order they appear in the file:

```
# KEEP ALIVE #
# OPTIMIZE WEBSITE #
# 404 #
```

When I add a fourth element -

```
# EXPIRES CACHING #:
# KEEP ALIVE #
# OPTIMIZE WEBSITE #
# EXPIRES CACHING #
# 404 #
```

The 404 command fails.

Is there a correct sequence that these instructions should follow in order for them to work?

```
## KEEP ALIVE ##
<ifModule mod_headers.c> 
Header set Connection keep-alive 
</ifModule>
## KEEP ALIVE ##  

## OPTIMIZE WEBSITE ##
<IfModule mod_deflate.c> 
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html text/plain text/xml text/css             application/x-javascript 
BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4 gzip-only-text/html 
BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4\.0[678] no-gzip 
BrowserMatch \bMSIE !no-gzip !gzip-only-text/html 
</IfModule>
## OPTIMIZE WEBSITE ## 

## EXPIRES CACHING ##
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
ExpiresActive On
ExpiresByType image/jpg "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType text/css "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType text/html "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/pdf "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType text/x-javascript "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/x-shockwaveflash "access plus 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access plus 1 year"
ExpiresDefault "access plus 1 month"
</IfModule>
## EXPIRES CACHING ##

## 404 ##
ErrorDocument 404 /404.html
## 404 ##
```

Comment: Your sequence is fine. The issue could be caused from the code within the sequence itself. Could you please share the full contents of your `.htaccess` file. Otherwise it is just guess work. Which helps nobody.

Comment: Okay - very good point - I believe there is a limit as to how much i can write - so ## KEEP ALIVE ##
<ifModule mod_headers.c> 
Header set Connection keep-alive 
</ifModule>
## KEEP ALIVE ##

Comment: you should edit your question and post it in there. It is quite difficult to read it from the comments!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. You can format source code with the [Code Sample `{}`](https://i.imgur.com/3ppJhiE.png) toolbar button. You also have a preview pane right below the editor so you can see how changes look like before you publish them.

Comment: Many thanks for your comments - hope this helps. Sorry really struggling to work my way around with this.

Comment: @Joeh when I tested your `.htaccess` code on my server I recieved no errors and it runs without issue. Have you tried clearing your cache? Also, when you say the *"404 command fails"*, what do you mean? Does it show an error, or does it just not load your error page?

Comment: Hi, many thanks for your time and your reply. Good to know the code is correct and yes I've cleared the cache. The 404 failure - it show an error page and not my 404 page. That is all. Now i know the code is correct I'll throw the question at the guys that 'look after' the server. Again, many thanks for your input @thickguru

Comment: Before you do, just try and place your `404` code above your  `## OPTIMIZE WEBSITE ##` option and let me know the outcome.

Comment: did as you suggested and placed the 404 code above the ## OPTIMIZE WEBSITE ## - result was Internal Server Error and the page would not load.